# How to Intel IPL compile to Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, intel-ipp

I've just got a Intel IPL library(Intel® Image Processing Library v2.5)on web then I've done to install well.

And I found some examples in the installed folder but this is made only vs6.0 environment.

Otherwise, it works well in vs6.0.

I'd like to compile the Intel IPL library in VS2010.

How to the Intel IPL compile to Visual Studio 2010?

[image]

I've got a message when I build as following.

```
------ Build started: Project: room001, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
Build started 2015-11-21 오전 12:55:18.
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching ".\Release\room001.unsuccessfulbuild".
ClCompile:
  create.cpp
C:\Program Files\Intel\plsuite\include\ipl.h(778): warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (949). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
create.cpp(303): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\stdio.h(371) : see declaration of 'sprintf'
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Program Files\Intel\plsuite\examples\Tutorial.IPL\IPLROOMS\ROOM001\.\Release\room001.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Program Files\Intel\plsuite\examples\Tutorial.IPL\create.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(992,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(room001) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (create). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
Link:
  room001.vcxproj -> C:\Program Files\Intel\plsuite\examples\Tutorial.IPL\IPLROOMS\ROOM001\.\Release\room001.exe
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file ".\Release\room001.unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching ".\Release\room001.lastbuildstate".

Build succeeded.

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.08
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Would you please help me please? I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi! Could you try to start room001.exe from command line window or from explorer. They may show you if your application misses any DLL.

Comment: @Sergey Khlystov thanks i'll try it and let you know. Otherwise, it works well in vs6.0.

Comment: @SergeyKhlystov : I can't find  "room001.exe" in  room001 folder anywhere. also cookroom too.

Comment: I am looking into build log... What about C:\Program Files\Intel\plsuite\examples\Tutorial.IPL\create.exe file? May it be the target file? Search for VS' MSB8012 warning message in the web.